# How to reverse "sudo chown -R 501:20"

Tags: node.js, npm

Ran npm i -g {library} inside my project and npm gave me an error because I didnt use sudo. instead of using sudo on a second attempt, I followed npm's suggestion to run `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/vorousjames/.npm"` (inside my project).

now anytime I run an npm command (anywhere), I get bash: `/Users/vorousjames/.npm-global/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

How do I fix this so I can use npm again?

Answer (score 1):

try running this in the terminal
`export PATH="/Users/vorousjames/.npm:$PATH`
if it works add that to your .bash_profile

Comment: can you run npm after that?

Comment: npm -v & npm I {library} gives me: `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15) .....`

Comment: Do you have nvm installed? type `nvm list` if you do try switching node versions see if it helps.

Comment: nvm list gave me `bash: nvm: command not found`. so im guessing the chown command removed it?

Comment: come to think of it, I dont remember installing nvm at any point. how will installing it help with my npm issue?

Comment: No you probably had npm installed with no version manager. Run this `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash` It will install nvm then do `nvm install --lts` which will install the latest long term support version of node. This will be added to your home folder in .npm directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202752/discussion-between-yoshinator-and-jim).